# Create new field into a table with Spring at runtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dynamic, runtime, field

I'm developing an API with Spring Framework in Java, and I have to create a field in my table at runtime, like this: the user save some information (like a simple String), and this information becomes a field of the table.

If you have some solution, let me know.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_myentity")
public class MyEntity {

    //fields, but dynamic in runtime!

}
```

**Note:** I don't want create a table with the field_name and make a relationship. Must be a field dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the answer to this is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502498/how-to-add-a-column-dynamically-in-hibernate-4-with-jpa-in-mysql)
even though you're using Spring instead of Hibernate as your data access framework. You'll want to just manually execute the DDL statements for `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` to add the column, but your Entity class wouldn't dynamically have more member variables created.

Comment: Understood Smith, you help me to find a solution for my problem, this answer should be accepted, thank you!