# How to dynamically add columns in Database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, hibernate

I have a spring boot project with Mysql & Hibernate, all I need is to provide a privilege to the user to change or alter columns of the database dynamically(runtime), I haven't found any good approach for that XML approach is quite hectic and will require a lot changes to be made.

Example:

A table User with columns
"Username" & "Password"

And from UI client will add another column "email" so it should make changes in Database table.

Comment: Hibernate is not the tool for this. You would need to either update a class file or an XML file at runtime. The issue is that this is then only available to that specific user. At best you can let the user alter the table, but propagating it to hibernate/java code isn't feasible at all

Comment: If your program is not specifically designed to manage database schemas, then wanting the user to dynamically add additional columns themselves usually means that your data model needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

What you are specifically asking here would need changes to your entities during runtime, and that is not possible. You can achieve a similar solution by adding one additional column `customerAttributes` to the `User` table and store that information as map:

```
@Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)
private Map<String, Object> customerAttributes;
```

There is a good tutorial for that: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-persist-json-object